# Using image sprite to show the hover and active state in html button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve three different state ACTIVE, PRESSED, INACTIVE

Image files (they are actually same height:
[image: Left]

[image: right]

What I am looking to do is have three different texts:
CLINICIAN, NON CLINICIAN, & BOTH

By default all three texts will have the top 1/3 of the image, on hover the middle 1/3 of the image and on press the bottom 1/3 of the image.
I also want the CSS to resize the image based on the text with about 10px padding on each side.

I started off with something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.hb {
    background-image: url('l.png');
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;

}

.hb:hover { 
    background-position: 0 50px;
}

.hb:active{ 
    background-position: 0 -260px; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<span class="hb"><a href="/help/start">CLINICIAN</a></span>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am sure i am not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

span is an inline element you are making it block in css 
you should apply the class to the link rather than span

Comment: i just used a DIV statement :)